# Thread class will not start or Initialize

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pandas, zeromq

I am trying to create a ZMQ Subscriber that writes to a CSV every certain amount of time (The time doesn't matter as much).

The problem I'm having is my write_csv1 class doesnt even start or initialize and the code for initialization is the same for my ZMQ thread class. It was working before I added the threading.Condition and the c.acquires/c.release.

Any tips or pointers would be amazing.

```
import zmq
import pandas as pd
import time
import threading


c = threading.Condition()
df = pd.DataFrame()
s = 0
m = 0
h = 0
d = 0

def counter():
    global h,s,m,d
    while True:
        s += 1
        print("Second:{}".format(s))
        if s >=60:
            m +=1
            s = 0
        if m >= 60:
            h += 1
            m = 0
        if h >= 24:
            d += 1
            h = 0        
        time.sleep(1)

class write(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
    def write_csv(self):
        global df
        while True:            
            print('sleeping')            
            time.sleep(12)
            c.acquire()
            print('acquired')
            print(df)                 
            with open("FILE", 'a') as f:
                    df.to_csv(f, encoding = 'utf-8', index = False, header = False)
            c.release()
            z = zmq_thread()            
            z.run()        

class zmq_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
    def run(self):  
        global df
        print('DF Created')
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)      
        socket.connect("tcp://localhost:#####")
        socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'TOPIC') 
        print('socket connected')

        count = 0
        while True: 
            c.acquire()
            try:
                count +=1
                if count == 10:
                    print('ZMQ Break') 
                    c.notify_all()
                    c.release()
                    print('Lock released')
                    return df                
                message = socket.recv_string()
                message2 = socket.recv_string()        
                if message == 'TOPIC':
                    message2_split = message2.split(",")
                    message4 = pd.Series(message2_split)
                    df = df.append(message4, ignore_index=True)               
                    print('ZMQ Running')

            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break              



counter = threading.Thread(target = counter)
write_csv1 = write("Write_csv")
zmq_loop = zmq_thread('Start_ZMQ')    

counter.start()
write_csv1.start()    
zmq_loop.start()
```

Comment: Two things: In order to start a thread, you don't have to derive from the thread class, just like you don't derive from a file class in order to use a file. Secondly, you need to read [ask] and extract a [mcve]. Asking precise questions helps you find errors yourself. Also, without the MCVE, your question is considered off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not implementing `run()` method on write class.
You need to rename `write_csv(self)` to `run(self)`

Comment: Okay that worked to get it running. But now my while loop stops at c.acquire in my write class. Not sure why. This is my first foray into more complicated threading techniques.                    Funny enough my run() function in my ZMQ_thread class was what I originally named it. So... dumb luck